# Pass values String[] to String[] values

Tags: java, string, opencsv

I have the following code, where a .csv file is read, line by line, and stored in String[]  nextline , where the nextline[i] is populated by the respective content of the parsed file.
I got no problems in reading the .csv file, but i do have in storing them in another String[], since the System.out.println() gives me the following result, for all the lines:

```
Nextline[1]=Jan  4, 2011 18:33:15.988422000 / predata=null / Nextline[4]=54 / size:0
```

As you can see, the Strin[] has null value, why the content is not passed?
Thanks in advance

```
public class Amostra {
    int[] id = new int[20000];
    String[] predata = new String[20000];
    int[] size = new int[20000];

    Amostra(String namefile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Csv2Array(namefile);
    }

    private void Csv2Array(String newfile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        String[] nextline;
        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(newfile), ';', '\'', 1);
        while((nextline = reader.readNext()) != null){
            predata[i] = nextline[1];
            size[i] = Integer.parseInt(nextline[4]);
            id[i] = i;
            i++;
            System.out.println("Nextline[1]=" + nextline[1] + 
                    " / predata=" + predata[i] + 
                    " / Nextline[4]=" + nextline[4] + 
                    " / size:" + size[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: look at the reformatted code.  Isn't it easier to read?  If you use consistent formatting you will find that it is easier to spot errors.

Answer (score 6):

Your `i++` statement is located before the `System.out` so you are actually printing the next line (not parsed yet). You should move the `i++` line after the `System.out`

Comment: ...How did i miss that? I tried so many things...i need to sleep. Thx ;)

Comment: +1 - That's it!  Don't even need to look at the `CSVReader` API.